# How to store data in array to be stringified (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify, session-storage

Just started JS, have read a bunch of SO answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962403/how-to-stringify-json-to-javascript-array?rq=1) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223990/how-to-stringify-an-array-in-javascript), but still having trouble getting this to work. I have a list of `inventory` items, whenever one is clicked, I want the id of that one (stored as a data attribute) to be pushed to a `sessionStorage` cart object. Not functioning code below, comments show what the output is. It looks like I'm having a problem `JSON.stringifying` the array.

Help greatly appreciated.

```
    var cart = [];
    $(document).on("click", "#inventory", function() { // let's say i clicked on the #inventory whose data attribute for inventory_id is 13
      console.log($(this).data('inventory_id')) // outputs 13
      cart.push($(this).data('inventory_id')) 
    });
    console.log(cart) // outputs an array where Array[1] = 13 in last example
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cart)) // outputs a blank: []
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("cart"))  // outputs a blank: []
```

Comment: There's just one ***MAJOR*** flaw, ID's are **unique**, you can't have more than one element with the same ID.

Comment: And, also, all your logic is outside the click handler, and happens on page load only, not when something is clicked ?

Comment: no it all works fine, the logic is within the click handler, it's the `cart.push` line. Regarding the first issue, yes all of my IDs are unique

Comment: Put pushing to the array doesn't really do anything, other than pushing to the array, it doesn't update the storage or do anything else ?

Comment: oh you're saying i need to move the local storage into the click handler i see, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments discussion, right answer was just to put the `localStorage.setItem` in the event handler itself.

```
var cart = [];
$(document).on("click", "#inventory", function() { // let's say i clicked on the #inventory whose data attribute for inventory_id is 13
  cart.push($(this).data('inventory_id'));
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
});
```